# Grub 2.02 Freezes When Using Razer Black Widow Keyboard to make Selection

Tags: grub2, keyboard, freeze, 14.04

I updated from 13.10 to 14.04 yesterday. When my system reboots/starts, I see Grub.  The countdown ticks away until I use the keyboard to make a selection from the list.  Then, the count down stops and system freezes.  Nothing happens.  I've given it time with no luck.  If I do not press any key on the keyboard the countdown will tick away from 10 seconds and the default OS will boot (Ubuntu).

Suspecting the keyboard, I unplugged it.  Plug in an old keyboard and restarted.  I am able to make selections with no problem and enter either OS.  The Razer keyboard works without problem while Ubuntu is running. It appears Grub 2.02 does not like my Razer keyboard.  I have tried unplugging the mouse and headset, which is plugged into the keyboard.  Still this does not help.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try to enter BIOS and check if your keyboard is working after the first key is pressed at all. I had a same problem but it was hardware related, keyboard got frozen after a first key was pressed. Solution was to re-plug the keyboard after each key press or replacing the keyboard with a new one.